# Is it posible to Sum Objects from that are inside an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array like this

```
let arr = [
 "01/01/2020":[{"cantidad":10,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":15,"codigo":102}],
 "01/02/2020":[{"cantidad":15,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":12,"codigo":102}],
 "01/03/2020":[{"cantidad":12,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":20,"codigo":102}],
 "01/04/2020":[{"cantidad":18,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":26,"codigo":102}],
]
```

what I expect to do is to Sum it into a new array but the keys of the objects stays the same, like this

```
arr2=[
    0:{"cantidad":55,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":73,"codigo":102}
   ]
```

Is it possible to be done this way?

Comment: Yes, you can, but the `arr` variable does not make sense. You are trying to create an array, but are using object properties. Then those object values are arrays with malformed data. Is this supposed to be JavaScript, JSON, PHP?

Comment: `.reduce`, but your code has syntax errors.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of Lodash for these sort of utility methods. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapValues

Comment: Did you want your array to be defined as follows?  

`let arr = [
 {"01/01/2020":["{cantidad":10,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":15,"codigo":102}]},
 {"01/02/2020":["{cantidad":15,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":12,"codigo":102}]},
 {"01/03/2020":["{cantidad":12,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":20,"codigo":102}]},
 {"01/04/2020":["{cantidad":18,"codigo":101},{"cantidad":26,"codigo":102}]},
]
`

Comment: @sundaycode it is Js, I grouped those objects by date and keep the date as theirs indexes,because what I want to accomplish is to show it in a graph in an interactive way, is it a bad practice ?

Comment: @CarlosGamarra Please make sure your code is syntactically correct. The code that you posted is malformed.

Comment: @CarlosGamarra The keys are fine, however, they are in an array. In JS you can not define keys in an array. You'll need to use an object. Additionally, the values are arrays mixed with objects, but there are syntax issues. Some of the brackets are strings

Comment: @sundaycode I defined those key when I grouped them,I formatted correctly the code.